# background style not work inside ng-repeat with ionic slide box

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to add background to div in ionic slider with ng-repeat but its not work.

I have used the following code

**Template**

```
       <ion-slide-box auto-play="true" does-continue="true" slide-interval="2000">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in banners">
               <div class="box" ng-style="{'background': 'url('+img+') no-repeat top left'}"></div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.banners = [
                        "http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/image5_170127819_PxgeF3V.jpg",
                        "http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/images_1_JbTP6rz.jpg"
];
```

Please help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: Did you set width and height for .box div?

Comment: yes I set the width and height

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the element?  Does the style show up?

Comment: its not showing that component and if I remove ng-repeat and add the single image then it working

Comment: Is your ion-slide-box in ion-view?

Comment: yes ion-slide box in ion-content along with ion-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to add ng-style to ion-slide and also add height: 100vh to .slider.

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="slide in banners" ng-style="{'background': 'url('+slide+') no-repeat top left'}">
    <div class="box blue" ></div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/kresogalic/pen/bwGNRR)